# How to return the first row of feature class as a list in ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, list

I need to return the first record of a feature class as a list. Is this possible? I can't seem to figure it out using `row.getValue()` as it does not allow me to put a wildcard in there.

Comment: Are you looking to return a list of all the values for each of the fields in 1 list?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using, 10.1?

Comment: ArcGIS version 10.0

Comment: I just need the first row as a list, so something like [0,"NJ","123 street"]

Comment: @wannabe_n00b please [edit your question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/92536/edit) to include this information, as well as what you've tried. This site works best when questions include all necessary details rather than having to fish them out of the comments.

Answer (score 7):

Give this a try:

```
import arcpy

ds = "NAME OF DATASET"
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(ds)]
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor(ds)
outlist = []
for row in cur:
    for field in fields:
        outlist.append(row.getValue(field))
    break
```

Comment: I basically had this already, I was hoping I didn't need this many lines. BTW, you don't need to do list comprehension in your 4th line if you just do getValue(field.name)

Comment: If you already have this - I am not sure what you are looking for then?  This works!

Comment: @ian you could do: fields = arcpy.ListFields(ds)  then in the cursor simply do field.name, but I prefer my way in this case!

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for a 1-liner:

```
firstRow = next(([row.getValue(field) for field in (f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(ds))] for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(ds)), None)
```

This uses a [generator expression](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and the [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) built-in function to short-circuit the evaluation of the generator such that only the first row is fetched. The `None` argument avoids a `StopIteration` exception from being raised if there are no rows in the dataset.

This is a lot easier in 10.1, BTW ([arcpy.da cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) return tuples).

Comment: This is what makes Python so cool - so many different approaches to do the same thing! And it gets better all the time.

Comment: I was hoping arcpy had a built in that retrieved all attributes but this will have to suffice.

Comment: As I mentioned, at 10.1 and up it does with arcpy.da cursors.